# Confused on Iterator

Tags: java, collections

```
ArrayList ls = new ArrayList();
ls.add(45);
ls.add(30);
ls.add(19);
**Iterator it = ls.iterator();**
```

I'm confused how iterator() is called via ArrayList reference when Iterator is an Interface. Can anybody explain me the logic behind this?

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? What did you expect to happen here and why?

Comment: What is confusing about that? The `iterator` method returns an object which implements the `Iterator` interface. Have you already checked the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.iterator%28%29)?

Comment: [`List.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator--) defines it, and `List` is an interface too.

Comment: This question can't be answered in it's current form. I suggest you read the code for this class which may answer your question.

Comment: You should take a look at how polymorphism works. By declaring `it` to be an Iterator, you claim that `it` has the ability to iterate using the methods specified in the `Iterator` interface. However, you neither know nor care what the underlying type is (for example, ListIterator, ArrayIterator, CustomIterator, etc.) or how it implements those methods. You can just use them.

Answer (score 2):

**ArrayList** class has **iterator()** method.when you call **iterator()** method of ArrayList class by ArrayList object then **iterator() method returns reference of Iterator interface**.once you have reference of Iterator interface then you easily iterate through all data.

```
ArrayList ls = new ArrayList();//here we getting ArrayList object 
ls.add(45);
ls.add(30);
ls.add(19);
Iterator it = ls.iterator();//we call ArrayList class method which is iterator() by ls object of ArrayList class.
```

Answer (score 1):

This was something that initially confused me about interfaces when I was introduced. I was under the assumption that an interface cannot be declared because the methods had not been defined yet, and this is correct in the sense that you cannot **initiate** an interface, but an object can be a ***type*** interface, which is what you are saying in your code there.

An example which cleared it up for me was this following:

```
interface Adult {
    public void work();
    public void payTaxes();
    public void reproduces();
}

interface Child {
    public void goToSchool();
    public void doHomework();
}

interface Baby {
    public void soilDiaper();
    public void cry();
}

public class Human implements Adult, Child, Baby {
    @Override
    public void work() {...}
    @Override
    public void payTaxes() {...}
    @Override
    public void reproduces() {...}
    @Override
    public void goToSchool() {...}
    @Override
    public void doHomework() {...}
    @Override
    public void soilDiaper() {...}
    @Override
    public void cry() {...}
}

Adult dad = new Human();
Adult mom = new Human();
Child jack = new Human();
Baby jill = new Human();
```

In the above example, I have four people: dad, mom, jack, and jill. They are all humans, but I will treat each one differently. Mom and dad will be treated as Adults and I will only be able to use the methods in the Human class that match the interface pattern for an Adult. For jack, I can only use the child interface methods, and for jill, only the Baby interface methods.

To tie this back to your question, the it object you are creating is being given an object that conforms to the Iterator interface, but it is not being given an object that *is* an Interface. It is being given an object that *conforms* to the Iterator interface.

Comment: This doesn't really make semantic sense. Interfaces should be the most general "layer" of the inheritance hierarchy, with implementing subclasses getting more and more specific. In this case, `Human` should be the interface, with `Adult`, `Baby`, and `Child` being implementing classes. Otherwise you're claiming that *all* humans are able to `work`, `payTaxes`, `goToSchool`, `reproduce`, etc...

Comment: By declaring the human as the base class and then having it implement several interfaces (`Adult`, `Baby`, `Child`), I am allowing for changes to the humans in the code as they grow up. For instance, when jack becomes an adult, I only need to change how I will interact with Jack. Jack is and always will be a `Human`, but eventually, Jack will be an `Adult` and therefore I will treat him as such.

Comment: well thanks for your efforts, but as you explained in your example that 'we'll be able to use the methods in the Human class that match the interface pattern for an Adult'. So,is iterator() defined in Iterator interface? As we're using that method via ArrayList reference

Comment: `Arraylist.iterator()` returns an object that conforms to the Iterator interface. All the methods that are guaranteed in the Iterator interface will be at your disposal. This is what you are being told in that line of code. You are expecting an object which conforms to the Iterator interface, which why it is an object of *type* Iterator.

Comment: well, i got it.. In the java doc API, inside ArrayList class, there's a iterator() which is returning a object of Itr() where **Itr** is a private Inner class implementing Iterator interface.  Thus, when iterator() method is called via ArrayList reference it returns an object of class ArrayList$Itr which is Iterator type. @blahfunk

Answer (score 0):

`iterator` is name of a method of `ArrayList` class and this method returns a reference to `Iterator` interface.